# Using CustomTKinter, how could I insert a moving gif into my GUI application?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, gif, customtkinter

I would like to insert an animated GIF of Maxwell the cat into my GUI application (based with CustomTkinter) instead of an indeterminate progress bar. I'm struggling to find a way on how to do this. Please help (also thanks in advance!)

Edit:
This was the correct solution. Note, CustomTkinter behaves differently from Tkinter. StackOverflow closed my question, but it could be relevant to anyone who uses CTk.

```
# How to insert a moving GIF into a CustomTkinter GUI 
def update_gif(self, frame_index):
   
    # initialize first frame of gif
    frame = self.frames[frame_index]
    gifImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame.resize((150, 85)))
    
    
    # create label for gif to pack to
    self.img_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self, image=gifImage, text="")
    self.img_label.pack()
    
    # calculate next frame index
    frame_index = (frame_index + 1) % len(self.frames)
    
    # recursive function call to update_gif() to update gif
    self.after(15, self.update_gif, frame_index)  # Update every 15 milliseconds (adjust the interval as needed)
      
def display_gif(self):
               
    # create list of still images to cycle through
    self.frames = []
    spinningCatGif = "cat-spinning.gif"
    gif = Image.open(spinningCatGif)
 
    # while loop to keep gif moving (cycling through still images)
    while True:
        self.frames.append(gif.copy()) # append copy of current gif frame to list
        gif.seek(len(self.frames)) # view each frame in list


    self.update_gif(0)  # Start updating and playing the GIF
```

Comment: You should use only one label instead of creating new label for every frame. Also it is better to resize those frames when adding to the list.